# Where do I put my C# delegate declaration, in a file of its own?

Tags: c#, delegates

Out of habit I tend to put classes/structs/enumerations in separate files when not nested.

For delegates, it seems like overkill to create a seperate file for a one liner:

```
public delegate string MyDelegateThatIsNotNestedInAnyClass ( string par );
```

I usually add it to the bottom of the most closely related class file. I was just wondering what other people do?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I tend to put each type in a separate code file. Doing so will help you navigate in Solution Explorer, though ReSharper rocks with "[Go To File](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/features/navigation_search.html#Go_to_File)"

[image]
<sub>(source: [jetbrains.com](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/features/screenshots/40/navigation_gotofile.png))</sub>

and "[Go To Type](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/features/navigation_search.html#Go_to_Type)":

[image]
<sub>(source: [jetbrains.com](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/features/screenshots/40/navigation_gototype.png))</sub>

Comment: Your images are now broken

Answer (score 3):

I usually add it to the .cs file of the class which implements the delegate function (at the namespace level).  If there are several of these, I put it in a separate file.

If I know for sure that only one class will implement the delegate function, I nest it in the implementing class.

Answer (score 2):

If it's closely related enough to belong in the same file as the class, then you can probably justify nesting it in the class. Then you'll have no trouble remembering which class file it's in.

If there's no single class that's an obvious choice to nest in, creating the one-line file is probably worthwhile since you'll never waste time trying to remember which class file you decided to put it in.

Answer (score 1):

I personally add it before a closely related class definition.  I make good use of namespaces, though, so I don't pollute!

Answer (score 1):

I allways declare my own events, even if I don´t need them in the sence that a generic event would suffice. The reason for that is that the class name of the event gives the code so much more readability and also not seldom the declared event will be needed further down the road for some reason.
Since I have an event class, I allways put the delegate above the class declaration of the event. They are closely coupled and if you need to listen to the event then you´ll need both the event and the delegate. I don´t know if this violates some design rules of any kind, but this has worked nicely for me.

Answer (score 0):

Usually, I just use:

```
Func<string, string>
```

these days

Comment: While I agree that this generic delegate does take a lot of the work away from having to declare your own delegates (since it can accommodate many of them), it's really not an answer to his question so I can't upvote.

Comment: I swear I'm the only person who actually downvotes irrelevant answers anymore.

Comment: @jfar: Are you aware that you bear a striking resemblance to Victor Creed (aka Sabertooth) from X Men Origins: Wolverine?

Comment: @Adam, really?  I don't see it.

Comment: Arguably the question is how to make sure that delegate definitions are easy to locate, and arguably using `Func<,>` is a legitimate way to do that since it puts the definition right where you use the delegate. Maybe.

Comment: Bah, maybe its just me, I guess answering "How do I do 'x'?" with "Why not try 'y'"? can sometimes be valuable.

Comment: This is a relevant (alternate) solution.